# Laravel Eloquent: Можно ли в один и тот же объект дважды записать Eloquent модель?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

[image: Код функции]

$newsBodyText принимает в первый раз нужное значение, а во второй раз null.
Объект который $newsBodyText пытается принять во второй раз действительно существует. Вопрос: почему так происходит?

Comment: плохая практика дергать что-то из БД в цикле. Попробуйте использовать конструкцию [whereIn](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/queries#where-clauses), и работать с результатами

Comment: Я понимаю, что это нехорошо и давно реализовал всё по другому. Но, мне все равно интересно, почему ошибка?